# Where can I get this connector / what's it called

Tags: soldering

[image]

It's for connecting an LCD to the driver board via a flex ribbon style cable shown below:
[image]

Also, is there any hope that I can solder this with a hot air gun?

Comment: That's a connector for an FPC/FFC cable.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi designs, including the bill of materials, are open source. You should be able to look this up yourself.

Comment: You can get them on digikey. Just make note of the pitch, and which side the contacts are on (top or bottom). I think hot air will be likely to melt the connector. I would either use re-flow or a soldering iron and a microscope.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the information however this isn't a Raspberry Pi. It's an driver board that can be used with a Pi over HDMI. The connector that I have circled is not present on the Pi board.

Comment: @Toor Found it. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Alfro: You needed to add the part number and link in the question. I think you've got the info you needed now.

Comment: @AlfroJang80: As for whether or not you'll be able to solder it with a hot air gun... More than likely not. You'll likely melt the plastic before you get all the joints the way you want them. One easy way you could solder it is with some solder paste on each of the pins, and then with a fine tip soldering iron just tap each pin till they're connected. You could try the paste with a hot air gun, but again, you risk melting the connector. If you have some reflective tape you can put over the connector to shield it from some heat, that would help.

Comment: @Transistor Apologies. Yep I've got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPC/FFC connector.
https://eu.mouser.com/Connectors/FFC-FPC/_/N-axjog?P=1y95khu&Keyword=FFC&FS=True 
Do mind the pitch, Top/Bottom connection style, and so on...

Comment: Can be soldered with a normal soldering iron and some flux